# Vyper and ethereum: how do I read a public constant function on another contract?

Tags: vyper

I'd like to call a constant function on one contract (X) from another contract (Y). I have the ABI and address for X. X and Y are both on Ropsten. I can interact with X fine using, for example, MEW.

Here is the code for X:

```
@public
@constant
def read() -> bytes32:
    return 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000059f43ef8557c30000
```

And the ABI:

```
[{"name": "read", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 283}]
```

Contract Y looks like this:

```
feedaddress: public(address)
feed: public(bytes[32])

@public
def __init__():
    self.feedaddress = 0xAb3F6737b0cf41e8a6AE297A3833021f8af2a3aC

@public
def myread():
    self.feed = raw_call(self.feedaddress, 'read', outsize=32, gas=msg.gas)

@public
def setfeedaddress(_new: address):
    self.feedaddress = _new
```

It returns "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]" on etherscan. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to [`raw_call`](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/built-in-functions.html#raw-call) should be the bytes you're sending to the other contract. In order to invoke the function `read()`, you should be sending the bytes `0x57de26a4` (the function signature: first 4 bytes of the keccak256 hash of `"read()"`).

Comment: I've used `raw_call(self.feedaddress, 'x57xdex26xa4', outsize=32, gas=msg.gas)` as well as '0x57de26a4' and '57de26a4' and all return the same error as above. I'm writing the result into a bytes[32] not a bytes32 (which won't compile). Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Vyper yet, but I assume you want `raw_call(self.feedaddress, 0x57de26a4, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Following a question on github, it turns out that raw_call is unnecessary because Vyper's contract interface is ABI compatible. Using the above example, the following works just fine:

```
contract Beread:
    def read() -> bytes32: constant

feedaddress: public(address)
feed: public(bytes32)
beread: Beread


@public
def __init__():
    self.feedaddress = 0x161E2Eea68ac57F3C7220170435396Fd7089d9fE

@public
def myread():
    self.beread = self.feedaddress
    self.feed = self.beread.read()

@public
def setfeedaddress(_new: address):
    self.feedaddress = _new
```

See [help with raw_call](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper/issues/1104) for how to use that function directly.